# Solar Thermal Collector to Boil Water (100 deg C)

Tags: heat-transfer, solar-energy

Is it possible to build a Solar Thermal Collector that boils water to 100 deg C?

I've seen a lot of Solar Thermal Collectors that claim to be able to boil water, but every example demonstration that I've seen that shows water boiling where the water is less than 100 degrees celsius. And most of these also demonstrated with water directly in the evacuated tube, not connected to a tank.

I'm looking to design a Solar Thermal Collector that can maintain water in a tank at 100 deg C, perhaps with aid of linear parabolic solar concentration.

I understand there'd be challenges in such a design, such as water vapor pressure. But is it possible? Has it been done before?

Can a Solar Thermal Collector be built that maintains a ~10L tank of water at 100 deg C using only solar radiation to heat the water?

Comment: Do you require the use of a linear projected parabola, rather than a circular projected parabola? The latter is likely to give you better collection over a smaller surface area and may also be easier to handle. Ten liters is quite a bit of water and will take some time to heat. Ten liters in a kettle on a powerful stove is not heated in a matter of a few minutes.

Comment: Please explain a demonstration that involves water boiling at temperatures below 100 °C? The only sensible aspect that could explain this is high altitude.

Comment: Is English your second language? Because you say boil water to 100C which doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you mean heat water to 100C? Or just simply boil water which already implies 100C? at sea level? And the answer is of course, yes but it really depends on how little water you're heating at how massive a solar collector you have.

Comment: Solar collectors run under oressure as they can exceed 100 deg C. Some are designed to produce steam. When the pump fails some collectors can reach about 200 deg C. Check out Solar Engineering of Thermal Processes by Duffie & Beckmann.

Comment: why do you think that it may not be possible?

Comment: See https://www.absolicon.com/t160-production-line/heat-steam-and-cooling/

Comment: As stated in the question, I have yet to find a demonstration of a system that shows water boiling at 100C. All the video demos I've found on YouTube say "look there's bubbles; it's boiling" and then they show the temp is ~93C. A demo of a system running at >100C would be perfect. Solar Mike's link is just marketing. I see no demo. I appreciate that it's possible and I'm sure it exists, so please answer this question with a link to such a system that demonstrates this. Ideally, also with open-source designs so it can be replicated.

Comment: sorry no complete open source designs since energy from sun varies with where you are and what the weather is like.  Glass pressure vessel with black coated (sealed) stainless steel container for water sjould get the job done on a sunny day with enough reflectors.  I suggest learning how to calculate insolation yourself to then scale...although heat loss to ambient atmosphere maay end up the bigger factor.

Comment: *molten sodium concentrated-solar plants* heat various salts to past melting point, and use this to as a heat resirvoir, at several hundred C, to then boil water even after the sun has set, and use the steam to drive steam turbines and make electricity.  50-100MW scale installations demonstrated a while back now. Expensive way to make your tea, but obv. not impossible

Answer (score 1):

They sell a Solar kettle on Amazon. It does boil water for camping personal coffee and tea. If you contact the manufacturer they may have larger units.

.

[image: solar kettle.]

Comment: That's the best example of a design that doesn't meet the requirements outlined in my question. They do not demonstrate or suggest that it can heat water to 100 deg C.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield, you are right the ad claims 93.4 degrees in one hour. There is no indication that it will not reach 100 celsius in a longer time. If the concern is the tank you would need a large mirror and some kind of insulation. But as for the temperature in school we used to burn the paper with a magnifier lens in the lab!